# How to configure MonoDevelop for Design-by-Contract (ccrewrite)

Tags: monodevelop

C#/Mono enables programming/design-by-contract: one can specify "require" and "ensure" statements. This is done with the `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` library.

If one reads the specifications, it is required to "rewrite" the program before executing it with `ccrewrite`. This page http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d0bc7e9-a1bc-469c-982a-47232308f131/ccrewrite seems to suggest that the action must be executed before building the assembly which is strange because the program will be overwritten after building.

What should one do to enable design-by-contract in MonoDevelop?

Comment: `ccrewrite` runs after the assembly is built; it "rewrites" the assembly with the contract ILCode. Also, this seems to be about programming or software development, so I'm voting to move it to [SO]. It should be migrated automatically when enough votes are cast.

Comment: Well it's about programming, but it's not about code. It's about how to configure a program that develops code. (No problem to move it, but I considered posting it on SO, but then argued it had not much to do with writing code oneself). Many thanks for the answer...

Comment: [SO] is about all things programming, not just code. :) There's definitely a bit of gray area when it comes to the tools, but the litmus test I usually use is "If I asked this of a computer-literate non-programmer (e.g., IT, Sysadmin, Network engineer), would they have any clue what I'm talking about?" If the answer is "Yes" -> [su], if the answer is "No" -> [SO]. Hope that helps :)